# Replicating Except in Access with a single table

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a table structured like this:

```
tblCase
+--------+---------------------+------------+
| CaseID | Reference           | ListID     |
+--------+---------------------+------------+
| 1      | A                   | 101        |
+--------+---------------------+------------+
| 2      | B                   | 101        |
+--------+---------------------+------------+
| 3      | A                   | 102        |
+--------+---------------------+------------+
| 4      | B                   | 102        |
+--------+---------------------+------------+
| 5      | C                   | 102        |
+--------+---------------------+------------+
```

I'm trying to write a query that returns only references that are in ListID x but are not in ListID y.

So for example, with this data, I'd compare List ID 101 and List ID 102, and return only Reference C, since Reference C is found only in ListID 102.

Something like

```
SELECT Reference FROM tblCase WHERE ListID = 102
EXCEPT
SELECT Reference FROM tblCase WHERE ListID = 101
```

But Except doesn't work in Access, and I'm not sure how to replicate it in this situation. I've found other similar questions answered, but haven't been able to adapt the answers successfully to my situation.

Thanks

EDIT: Resolved using SylvainL's suggestion. Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One easy way would be to use the Not Exists() statement; something like:

```
Select Reference from MyTable t1
Where ListId = 102 and
  Not Exists (Select * from MyTable t2 where t2.Reference = t1.Reference and T2.ListId = 101)
```

Using a Left Join from MyTable toward itself and looking for Null values is another solution.